# multer can't read multiple files

Tags: node.js, ajax, file-upload, multer

I'm trying to send both array of image files and some input values with ajax to node js.
ajax code:

```
const addForm = document.querySelector('#addForm');
let fd = new FormData();


addForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {

    event.preventDefault();

    const newProduct = {
        Cost: document.getElementById('addPcost').value,
        Size: document.querySelectorAll('[name="size"]:checked')[0].value,
        Material: document.querySelectorAll('[name="material"]:checked')[0].value,
        Color: document.getElementById('addPcolor').value,
        Category: document.querySelectorAll('[name="category"]:checked')[0].value
    }

    imageFiles.forEach(image => {
        fd.append("image", image);
    });
    fd.append("info", JSON.stringify(newProduct));

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/addproduct",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: fd,
        success: () => {
            Notiflix.Notify.Success("new product added successfully.");
        },
        error: (textStatus, err) => {
            Notiflix.Notify.Failure('<h2>Internal Server Error</h2><br>' + 'text status ' + textStatus + ', err ' + err);
        }
    });

});
```

and this is the node js side code:

```
app.post('/addproduct', (req, res) => {

    upload(req, res, (err) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }else {
            console.log(req.body);
        }
    });

});
```

> NOTE: the upload function is for multer

when I send the data multer returns an error:

> MulterError: Unexpected field

> code: 'LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE',
> field: 'image',
> storageErrors: []

why is this happening?
how can I upload an array of image files and form data with ajax to node js?
please show me if there is a better way.

thanks in advance.

**Edit:** multer config:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({

    destination: './public/images',
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }

});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
}).array("pImg");
```

Comment: Can you add `Multer` config in the question?

Comment: I just solved the problem. the array name I was using for multer was not the same as formData field. changed it to image and then I changed req.body.image to req.files and now I'm getting the results. It was just a stupid mistake. took 4 hours to solve.I posted all of the codes except the part that was broken. excuse me.